# How to override default text edit function in Jquery x editable?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am using jquery-ui xeditable and before calling edit submit, I have to validate the values by calling other methods. When I try to use `addclass` and `removeclass` it's going in to an infinite loop.

Here is the code:

```
$("*[id^=EqOwner_customerAssetId]").click(function(e) {  
    alert("Inside click..!");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventdefault();

    var fldId = "#" + this.id;
    var cusidflag = "#c" + this.id;
    var equipid = "#e" + this.id;

    $('.xeditable').editable('disable');
    if (($(cusidflag).val()) == "false" && $(equipid).val() != "") {
        $("#dialog-equipment-id-edit").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:'auto',
            width: '360',
            modal: true,                      
            buttons: [{ 
                text:  EDTranslations.ok,
                click: function() {     
                    $(this).dialog('close');                                 
                }
            }],
            close: function() {
                $('.xeditable').trigger('click');  
            }                            
        }); 
    }

    $(fldId).editable('editable-click');
});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is always easier to discuss a problem on a certain piece of code, where we can see what you tried.

Comment: Hi Uwe Allner, Thanks for your comments. I just added the code